# PHP Couchbase Client operation timed out

Tags: php, couchbase

I've installed Couchbase 2.1.1 Enterprise edition on Server A, PHP `Couchbase::Client` on servers B and C. Servers B and C are setup identically on RHEL 5.8 and PHP 5.3.3.

I'm facing issue on server C wherein, I'm able to establish Couchbase connection but any subsequent Read and Write throws following error.

> Failed to get a value from server: Operation timed out
>
> Failed to store value to server: Operation timed out

Same script works on server B without any issues. Kindly help me resolve the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Could you share the script?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there no firewalls and you don't use admin credentials

Comment: Servers A, B and C are VMs on same server and there's no Firewall installed. Server C is able to establish connection with Couchbase on Server A, but is unable to Read and Write.